# webpack: how to get JavaScript from "bower_components", not from "node_modules"

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, webpack, bower

Due the use of `main-bower-files` as part of the compiling tasks using Gulp, I can't `require` modules using webpack from `node_modules` dir because I would mess the CSS's / images / fonts processing tasks in my current asset system. So, **how can I tell webpack "when I `require` something, search into `bower_components` folder instead in `node_modules`"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [resolve.modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) option in your config:

```
resolve: {
  modules: ['bower_components']
}
```

With this it won't check `node_modules` at all, but if you'd like to fallback to `node_modules` when the module is not found in `bower_components`, you can add it as well, the priority is from left to right:

```
resolve: {
  modules: ['bower_components', 'node_modules']
}
```